# Vidalia for ubuntu (vidalia: cannot connect to X server :0)

Tags: vidalia, ubuntu

I installed the vidalia on ubuntu 14.04 using

```
apt-get install vidalia
```

the logs at `/var/logs/tor/log` tells that everything went OK (See https://gist.github.com/waqaskhan137/86a9e1029d90dda03a68). 
if i try in terminal  `vidalia` 
it says

```
GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient, 0 matched rules; type="method_call", sender="(null)" (inactive) interface="org.freedesktop.DBus" member="Hello" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.DBus" (bus)

(<unknown>:19383): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: No GSettings schemas are installed on the system
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

if i use the sudo it says

```
No protocol specified
vidalia: cannot connect to X server :0
```

If i try to run it using the gui it just doesn't show anything

[Video of the issue](https://youtu.be/delyyvVkFUo)

Thanks,

Comment: Vidalia is not supported anymore. So it is probable that no one can help here. However the error message states a problem with apparmor. You might try to disable AppArmor for a moment and start Vidalia. However in the long-term you should try to use Tor Browser and not Vidalia anymore.

Answer (score 1):

A [similar question was also asked](https://askubuntu.com/q/449824/236) at AskUbuntu. The recommendation there was to run the following commands. They remove the AppArmor profile for Vidalia and restart Tor:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.vidalia /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.vidalia
sudo /etc/init.d/tor start
```

If you start Vidalia now, it should work.